# Unrecognised selector +[AFAnalytics sharedAnalytics]?

Tags: xcode, ios11, ios12

I am currently getting my app ready for **iOS 12** however whenever I tap on any `UITextField` or `UITextView` the app crashes and I get this unrecognised selector error.

## What I've tried

- They're delegates are linked to the Files Owner (yes I know - the old term) but have unliked everything and stopped referencing it in the `UIViewController` however still get the same crash and error message.
- Added a brand new `UITextView`/`UITextField` but- again same crash error.
- Searched everywhere online but there has been nothing not anything useful.
- Only crashes on **iOS 12**. iOS 11 and lower work perfect, no issues.
- App uses **Firebase**, **Crashlytics/Fabric** and some other third-party libraries which are all using latest SDK/API version.

Closest thing I've found is that `AFAnalytics.h` is part of the `AssistantServices.framework` that I can't find in Xcode 10 Beta 6 nor in the public Xcode 9??

Honestly I'm starting to run out of ideas so any help to try and resolve this would be a massive help.

**Im writing in Objective-C.**

Full stacktrace: http://crashes.to/s/dd22fb06f7b

---

**UPDATE - 2/09/2018**
- Weirdly, setting the `Keyboard Type` to `E-mail Address` in interface builder the field works perfectly fine. Setting it to anything else crashes the app.

---

**UPDATE - 14/9/2018**
Another crash log seems to suggest that the error revolves around `[UIDictationConnection analytics]`?

Does this make any sense to anyone? - This is from a crash report by Apple.
[image]

---

**UPDATE - 2/10/2018**
I have discovered this error message:

`Class AFAnalytics is implemented in both /Users/ashleyrichards/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C155EF28-3C0B-4AFF-9EF6-0235295A26DC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/562B100D-F657-424E-8B77-99D0325F6035/Social Dummy.app/Social Dummy (0x10a33d610) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssistantServices.framework/AssistantServices (0x13654d178). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.`

I've search my entire project but haven't found any class relating to `AFAnalytics`.
For the record, I don't want to use `AFAnalytics`. I don't even know what it does.. How do I get rid of it?

Comment: Any Solution ? I am facing same problem

Comment: @iosgeek I haven't yet no. Still stuck on this. Someone did comment saying that it could be a static library in the project. What static libraries do you have in your app? My app is quite big so I have quite a lot - which makes it bit harder for me.

Comment: It is actually due to AFNetworking Lib used in App. In my app I have used AFNetworking and just Facebook Core Kit

Comment: Hmm. I don't use AFNetworking nor Facebook Core Kit. Do I use the Reachability library if you think that could be linked? I also use Firebase and Crashlytics too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found a workaround that prevents crash. We can use iOS runtime to swizzle class methods. The main idea is to redirect message from `+[AFAnalytics sharedAnalytics]` to `+[iOS12AFAnalyticsBug newSharedAnalytics]`. Class method "newSharedAnalytics" intentionally returns **nil** and messages to nil won't cause a crash. But use this workaround carefully since some code in your app uses AFAnalytics for some purposes.

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [iOS12AFAnalyticsBug fix];
    //your code
}
```

**iOS12AFAnalyticsBug.h**

```
@interface iOS12AFAnalyticsBug : NSObject

+ (void)fix;

@end
```

**iOS12AFAnalyticsBug.m**

```
#import "iOS12AFAnalyticsBug.h"
#include <objc/message.h>

void SwizzleClassMethod(Class originClass, SEL originSelector, Class destClass, SEL newSelector) {

    Method originMethod = class_getClassMethod(originClass, originSelector);
    Method newMethod = class_getClassMethod(destClass, newSelector);

    originClass = object_getClass((id)originClass);

    if (class_addMethod(originClass, originSelector, method_getImplementation(newMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(newMethod))) {
        class_replaceMethod(originClass, newSelector, method_getImplementation(originMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(originMethod));
    } else {
        method_exchangeImplementations(originMethod, newMethod);
    }
}

@implementation iOS12AFAnalyticsBug

+ (instancetype)newSharedAnalytics {

    return nil; //All messages to nil won't cause a crash

}

+ (void)fix {

    Class originClass = NSClassFromString(@"AFAnalytics");
    SEL originSelector = NSSelectorFromString(@"sharedAnalytics");

    SwizzleClassMethod(originClass, originSelector, self.class, @selector(newSharedAnalytics));
}

@end
```

Comment: This stops the crashing THANK YOU SO MUCH. I haven no idea what uses `AFAnalytics`. As I've mentioned in the description, I can not find any reference in any of the API's nor in my app anywhere so it is very confusing.

Comment: Same issue for me on iOS14, this solutions still works...although I don't know what AFAnalytics does... but according to this seems a os class. https://developer.limneos.net/index.php?ios=13.1.3&framework=AssistantServices.framework&header=AFAnalytics.h